# Execute maven task first thing

Tags: maven, module, maven-antrun-plugin

I have a multi-module maven project and would like to execute an ant task *before* maven starts building the reactor.

The only solution I've come up is to create a module that will execute this ant task, and have that module be the first in the list of `<modules>`, but I feel that is not the maven way (or is it?)

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thanks

**Edit:**

The reason I need this is because I have environmental settings I need to configure for this project only when a complete build is required.  The problem is, this ant task is quite expensive (10+ seconds), and so I don't want to run the task for individual module builds.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? By the way, maven sorts all modules and builds it according to the correct build order, so you will probably have your sibling modules depend on such a project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach seems to be correct. I have seen similar build scripts in some client projects. The first module contains only one build plugin : maven-antrun-plugin. 
Rest of modules are normal Maven pom files that see the environment settings updated by Ant.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I ended up having the script execute before every module is built, but optimized the script to be < 1 sec execution time.